# basic_time Exception with Spring-Data-elasticsearch:4.4.18

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hello dear community,

I have migrated from **Spring-data-elasticsearch**:3.x to **4.4.18** and since then I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat[] org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field.format() (Found data of type Lorg/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/DateFormat;.basic_date)
```

My fields are annotated as follows:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date)
private LocalDate promotionDateFrom;
```

Does anyone know in which format these have to be formatted so that I can save dates as a type? Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find a working solution in the forum.

My query looks like that and should be fine, right? It converts the String to a BASIC_ISO_DATE which should have the same format as the DateFormat.basic_date. Does maybe someone know another problem with the mapping of these types?

```
String yesterday = getNow().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
      campaignQueryBuilder.must().add(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("productDateEnd").gte(yesterday));
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: The error with the annotation types looks like it might come from some version mismatch in the used libraries, hard to say without a reproducible sample example project. This is not related to you query building. I don't think that this is related to building a native query. Btw 4.4x is out of maintenance almost a year now.

Comment: Thanks P.J.Meisch, we could just solve it by using the deprecated Custom pattern of LocalDate. And yes I know that 4.4 is out of maintenance but a higher refactoring would include to much changes which are not affordable for that product anymore.